# Ignore Emmet commands in files other than html and css

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

Is it possible to set up the Emmet package for Sublime Text 3 in a way that it ignores all shortcuts in files other than **HTML** and **CSS**?

I love to work with Emmet using `tab` in HTML and CSS files but I could use `tab` for something else when working with python for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `Emmet.sublime-settings` for `disable_tab_abbreviations_for_scopes` and `disable_tab_abbreviations_for_regexp` and `disable_tab_abbreviations`.

Some more infos about the tab handler can be found in their [README](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#tab-key-handler).